# Make a grouped Bar chart of two percentage variables in r

Tags: r, grouping, bar-chart, percentage

I wish to make a grouped bar chart of two binomial variables.

I recorded infection of oak leaves by powdery mildew upon the top (P.A) and bottom (U.PA) of leaves. They are organised as presence (represented with a "1") or absence (represented by a "0").

[This is an image showing the top of my dataframe.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUDgh.png)
It is organised by Date, leaf number, plant ID and the two binomial variables P.A and U.PA.

I can plot these separately in two bar charts.

[Percentage of leaves with Powdery mildew infection upon the upper surface of the leafs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTq0d.png)

[Percentage of leaves with powdery mildew upon the under surface of the leafs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBmcI.png)

Using this code:

```
plot(DFP$P.A ~ DFP$Date, ylim=c(0,0.2), main= "Leaves infected with powdery mildew on the upper surface", ylab = "Percentage of leaves infected", xlab= "Date")

plot(DFP$L.PA ~ DFP$Date, ylim=c(0,0.2), main= "Leaves infected with powdery mildew on the lower surface", ylab = "Percentage of leaves infected", xlab= "Date")
```

I essentially want to recreate the above two images into one. So grouped by date with the percentage of leaves infected out of the total number of leaves for U.PA and P.A but on the same chart.

I have seen there are a few topics about grouped bar charts on the site but I have been unable to apply this to my dataset, possibly as it is binomial data?   I apologise for my own ignorance with r but i am slowly learning.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My subset of my data using dput(DFY) as the full data won't fit:

structure(list(Date = structure(c(1532995200, 1532995200, 1530662400, 
1530662400, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1531785600, 
1531785600, 1531785600, 1529884800, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1529884800, 
1532995200, 1532995200, 1529884800, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1532995200, 
1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1532995200, 
1531785600, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1532995200, 
1530662400, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1529884800, 1532995200, 
1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1529884800, 
1531785600, 1530662400, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1529884800, 1530662400, 
1530662400, 1531785600, NA, 1531785600, 1530662400, 1531785600, 
1529884800, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 
1532995200, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1530662400, 
1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 
1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 
1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1531785600, 
1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1529884800, 1531785600, 1531785600, 
1531785600, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1531785600, 
1531785600, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1531785600, 
1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1529884800, 1530662400, 1531785600, 
1531785600, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1532995200, 
1531785600, 1529884800, 1529884800, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 
1532995200, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1530662400, 
1531785600, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1529884800, 1531785600, 1531785600, 
1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1530662400, 
1531785600, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1530662400, 1531785600, 
1532995200, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1532995200, 
1532995200, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1530662400, 
1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1531785600, 
1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1529884800, 
1530662400, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1530662400, 1529884800, 1531785600, 
1530662400, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 
1529884800, 1529884800, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1530662400, 
1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1529884800, 1529884800, 1529884800, 
1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1529884800, 1530662400, 
1529884800, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 
1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1531785600, 
1531785600, 1531785600, 1529884800, 1529884800, 1531785600, 1531785600, 
1532995200, 1529884800, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1531785600, 
1530662400, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1531785600, 
1531785600, 1530662400, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1530662400, 1532995200, 
1530662400, 1531785600, 1530662400, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1531785600, 
1530662400, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1532995200, 
1531785600, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1530662400, 
1531785600, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1530662400, 1532995200, 
1530662400, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1529884800, 
1529884800, 1530662400, 1529884800, 1531785600, 1529884800, 1529884800, 
1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 
1530662400, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 
1530662400, 1529884800, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1530662400, 
1531785600, 1529884800, 1532995200, 1529884800, 1532995200, 1530662400, 
1532995200, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1530662400, 
1531785600, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1531785600, 
1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 
1530662400, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1529884800, 1531785600, 1532995200, 
1530662400, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1532995200, 
1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1529884800, 1532995200, 1531785600, 
1530662400, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1531785600, 
1531785600, 1531785600, 1530662400, 1530662400, 1530662400, 1530662400, 
1529884800, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 
1531785600, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1530662400, 
1532995200, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1531785600, 
1530662400, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1529884800, 1530662400, 1532995200, 
1532995200, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 
1531785600, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1531785600, 
1532995200, 1531785600, 1529884800, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1531785600, 
1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 
1532995200, 1529884800, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1531785600, 
1532995200, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1529884800, 1532995200, 1531785600, 
1530662400, 1529884800, 1530662400, 1530662400, 1530662400, 1532995200, 
1531785600, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 
1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 
1531785600, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1531785600, 
1530662400, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1532995200, 
1529884800, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1529884800, 
1530662400, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1531785600, 
1531785600, 1530662400, 1529884800, 1531785600, 1529884800, 1530662400, 
1530662400, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1532995200, 
1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 
1529884800, 1529884800, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1529884800, 1532995200, 
1532995200, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1529884800, 1531785600, 
1529884800, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1531785600, 
1532995200, 1531785600, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1529884800, 
1530662400, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1530662400, 
1532995200, 1529884800, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1530662400, 
1530662400, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 
1532995200, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1531785600, 
1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1532995200, 
1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 
1532995200, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1531785600, 
1531785600, 1529884800, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1529884800, 1530662400, 
1530662400, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1531785600, 
1531785600, 1530662400, 1529884800, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1530662400, 
1530662400, 1530662400, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1529884800, 
1531785600, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1532995200, 
1530662400, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 
1530662400, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1530662400, 1532995200, 
1529884800, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1530662400, 1532995200, 
1530662400, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 
1532995200, 1530662400, 1529884800, 1529884800, 1530662400, 1530662400, 
1530662400, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1530662400, 
1532995200, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 
1530662400, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1532995200, 
1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1530662400, 
1530662400, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 
1532995200, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1529884800, 1530662400, 
1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1529884800, 
1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1529884800, 1529884800, 1530662400, 
1531785600, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1531785600, 
1531785600, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1530662400, 1530662400, 
1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1531785600, 
1531785600, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1530662400, 
1531785600, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 
1531785600, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1529884800, 1532995200, 
1529884800, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1531785600, 
1532995200, 1529884800, 1530662400, 1530662400, 1530662400, 1531785600, 
1532995200, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1530662400, 1529884800, 
1530662400, 1529884800, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1531785600, 1530662400, 
1532995200, 1529884800, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 
1532995200, 1529884800, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1530662400, 1529884800, 
1529884800, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1530662400, 
1531785600, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1530662400, 1530662400, 1530662400, 
1532995200, 1531785600, 1529884800, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 
1531785600, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1529884800, 1530662400, 
1531785600, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1529884800, 1531785600, 
1532995200, 1532995200, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 
1532995200, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1530662400, 
1531785600, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 
1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200, 
1530662400, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1529884800, 1531785600, 
1532995200, 1531785600, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1530662400, 1530662400, 
1532995200, 1529884800, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1529884800, 
1532995200, 1530662400, 1529884800, 1532995200, 1531785600, 1530662400, 
1530662400, 1530662400, 1529884800, 1530662400, 1532995200, 1530662400, 
1531785600, 1530662400, 1531785600, 1532995200, 1532995200), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Plant_ID = c("190", "324", "493", 
"111", "511", "299", "309", "539", "431", "121", "182", "587", 
"29", "436", "403", "112", "42", "344", "68", "430", "729", "509", 
"428", "239", "326", "311", "71", "422", "444", "393", "X404", 
"554", "345", "319", "356", "548", "34", "646", "117", "563", 
"592", "103", "508", "767", "460", "44", "572", "398", "337", 
"554", "239", "580", "377", NA, "448", "X404", "744", "184", 
"298", "645", "584", "643", "426", "206", "258", "617", "306", 
"703", "12", "643", "726", "380", "126", "426", "374", "156", 
"344", "1", "635", "754", "169", "142", "617", "172", "477", 
"727", "25", "342", "502", "286", "530", "249", "512", "546", 
"35", "370", "653", "116", "621", "X404", "239", "751", "169", 
"281", "346", "156", "463", "537", "622", "376", "775", "575", 
"382", "532", "208", "90", "475", "311", "582", "534", "644", 
"79", "404", "460", "470", "299", "94", "608", "214", "83", "623", 
"315", "582", "619", "283", "29", "73", "19", "757", "589", "85", 
"526", "155", "535", "618", "335", "568", "330", "262", "354", 
"234", "597", "296", "444", "411", "232", "775", "591", "284", 
"373", "639", "377", "603", "41", "511", "146", "525", "508", 
"233", "335", "235", "593", "25", "564", "603", "334", "173", 
"44", "232", "716", "57", "3", "593", "589", "40 NL G9", "32", 
"411", "545", "77", "285", "435", "247", "630", "481", "409", 
"325", "516", "231", "776", "225", "299", "448", "282", "483", 
"690", "251", "480", "574", "156", "557", "20", "368", "76", 
"253", "380", "139", "610", "509", "117", "35", "340", "643", 
"7", "736", "320", "311", "59", "430", "721", "81", "74", "335", 
"765", "639", "326", "60", "477", "296", "200", "630", "602", 
"531", "70", "535", "530", "104", "233", "95", "572", "227", 
"617", "557", "346", "214", "574", "114", "707", "72", "622", 
"177", "330", "97", "33", "127", "779", "308", "256", "363", 
"436", "333", "287", "529", "516", "765", "644", "128", "61", 
"3", "436", "303", "310", "136", "324", "731", "572", "769", 
"591", "283", "762", "441", "101", "640", "5NL29", "155", "639", 
"336", "719", "647", "30", "539", "26", "601", "416", "70", "166", 
"224", "284", "358", "317", "236", "70", "71", "120", "147", 
"584", "240", "421", "16", "460", "209", "424", "510", "632", 
"412", "603", "346", "563", "628", "423", "572", "85", "138", 
"299", "118", "172", "586", "3", "643", "77", "308", "410", "623", 
"190", "222", "175", "283", "651", "378", "396", "298", "730", 
"546", "454", "271", "533", "356", "331", "702", "303", "572", 
"290", "580", "179", "304", "214", "226", "255", "737", "324", 
"651", "43", "300", "483", "623", "291", "335", "574", "475", 
"283", "271", "74", "282", "30", "300", "767", "113", "73", "591", 
"170", "276", "557", "532", "22", "365", "505", "640", "471", 
"310", "346", "330", "551", "686", "667", "543", "398", "114", 
"338", "19", "75", "29", "562", "31", "307", "183", "352", "18", 
"86", "564", "155", "311", "767", "460", "590", "4", "260", "631", 
"391", "180", "21", "645", "179", "86", "646", "358", "564", 
"531", "290", "250", "195", "368", "356", "155", "169", "340", 
"666", "721", "333", "585", "77", "586", "533", "641", "83", 
"244", "258", "586", "272", "17", "256", "268", "196", "166", 
"594", "59", "174", "299", "366", "14", "642", "306", "251", 
"665", "229", "729", "517", "413", "563", "372", "610", "460", 
"344", "276", "411", "675", "777", "617", "733", "201", "296", 
"467", "375", "623", "459", "572", "433", "764", "643", "770", 
"580", "517", "225", "335", "319", "541", "178", "529", "361", 
"520", "403", "407", "492", "116", "194", "226", "535", "57", 
"497", "74", "441", "586", "60", "9", "762", "347", "403", "186", 
"444", "728", "590", "172", "415", "551", "387", "59", "454", 
"120", "603", "169", "377", "317", "281", "31", "276", "423", 
"297", "249", "237", "405", "578", "262", "399", "744", "387", 
"299", "640", "296", "86", "153", "362", "412", "623", "317", 
"246", "625", "780", "188", "522", "258", "307", "599", "317", 
"564", "39", "3", "308", "367", "86", "499", "372", "25", "508", 
"100", "70", "126", "215", "88", "175", "629", "70", "597", "183", 
"528", "180", "592", "349", "232", "32", "644", "588", "67", 
"308", "520", "290", "307", "425", "428", "184", "13", "299", 
"646", "22", "95", "533", "118", "291", "643", "574", "168", 
"321", "741", "356", "87", "494", "203", "439", "357", "58", 
"372", "767", "411", "232", "282", "392", "530", "756", "240", 
"619", "537", "448", "31", "178", "487", "20", "2", "373", "591", 
"136", "503", "222", "581", "103", "503", "338", "312", "56", 
"128", "329", "303", "312", "157", "393", "360", "332", "11", 
"644", "531", "416", "324", "14", "391", "365", "280", "367", 
"352", "248", "78", "316", "153", "102", "442", "108", "582", 
"280", "108", "242", "91", "253", "113", "728", "180", "680", 
"294", "G10", "115", "237", "30", "71", "143", "9", "1", "558", 
"26", "174", "86", "690", "475", "316", "X102", "756", "29", 
"350", "533", "169", "83", "508", "607", "47", "176", "313", 
"779", "166", "29", "642", "716", "594", "88", "413", "503", 
"689", "169", "671", "561", "273", "116", "460", "71", "326", 
"408", "631", "236", "32", "744", "2", "322", "81", "283", "14", 
"628", "339", "346", "344", "241", "233", "626", "228", "334", 
"525", "564", "243", "388", "358", "548", "316", "174", "635", 
"57", "31", "42", "6", "438", "116", "509", "535", "762", "562", 
"241", "83", "239", "426", "308", "38", "579", "448", "300", 
"135", "588", "501", "68", "570", "481", "313", "335", "509", 
"424", "602", "768", "639", "654", "729", "378"), Leaf = c(2, 
10, 4, 4, 7, 10, 5, 5, 5, 2, 3, 6, 4, 1, 5, 10, 2, 2, 11, 11, 
10, 10, 7, 45, 2, 1, 23, 3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 2, 4, 6, 2, 5, 7, 3, 
3, 1, 10, 14, 9, 7, 2, 3, 12, 8, 6, 30, 2, 4, NA, 5, 4, 6, 3, 
2, 13, 5, 12, 12, 5, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 20, 3, 8, 7, 16, 5, 5, 2, 
4, 9, 2, 4, 8, 16, 4, 2, 2, 8, 13, 5, 15, 3, 7, 3, 3, 4, 6, 4, 
8, 2, 1, 35, 4, 18, 2, 12, 5, 2, 13, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
16, 4, 1, 1, 7, 4, 5, 2, 1, 6, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 11, 9, 7, 1, 
9, 6, 2, 17, 1, 2, 4, 15, 5, 11, 7, 4, 11, 2, 8, 8, 21, 2, 5, 
5, 4, 10, 18, 7, 15, 1, 4, 5, 1, 9, 13, 19, 16, 13, 2, 4, 12, 
8, 1, 1, 11, 2, 6, 5, 14, 10, 3, 5, 1, 5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 6, 6, 3, 
1, 5, 14, 34, 2, 4, 1, 2, 11, 7, 4, 5, 3, 10, 4, 2, 5, 15, 3, 
2, 2, 8, 2, 6, 34, 9, 1, 6, 18, 4, 8, 2, 9, 9, 1, 5, 1, 23, 15, 
5, 2, 6, 14, 5, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 13, 7, 6, 8, 1, 22, 2, 7, 11, 
4, 4, 2, 11, 1, 1, 20, 1, 4, 5, 3, 5, 20, 5, 10, 1, 4, 4, 7, 
6, 1, 2, 3, 12, 13, 3, 13, 3, 3, 8, 17, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 8, 13, 
1, 6, 11, 2, 4, 1, 6, 3, 5, 9, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 13, 8, 3, 7, 
9, 3, 28, 2, 6, 2, 14, 1, 3, 5, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 17, 12, 16, 
6, 11, 3, 6, 9, 3, 11, 2, 11, 10, 6, 7, 4, 10, 3, 2, 3, 7, 2, 
6, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 2, 4, 7, 3, 3, 6, 8, 4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 6, 1, 1, 
7, 3, 3, 6, 6, 25, 14, 10, 1, 19, 1, 2, 21, 27, 6, 4, 8, 5, 10, 
16, 8, 9, 1, 5, 5, 4, 3, 8, 1, 8, 8, 6, 2, 5, 1, 7, 4, 3, 1, 
1, 5, 3, 18, 12, 15, 2, 6, 5, 8, 6, 5, 9, 6, 12, 3, 6, 13, 4, 
5, 1, 6, 2, 4, 14, 1, 10, 9, 5, 12, 7, 2, 4, 1, 3, 6, 12, 4, 
4, 6, 2, 5, 7, 6, 2, 8, 10, 2, 9, 1, 7, 8, 5, 21, 6, 3, 11, 16, 
14, 3, 8, 11, 1, 2, 1, 5, 5, 8, 5, 6, 1, 15, 9, 4, 14, 10, 2, 
5, 6, 4, 4, 2, 5, 1, 22, 8, 20, 1, 4, 6, 4, 13, 9, 2, 10, 3, 
4, 21, 2, 7, 9, 1, 1, 3, 6, 6, 7, 3, 16, 4, 23, 11, 11, 1, 6, 
2, 4, 7, 19, 4, 9, 4, 9, 7, 5, 3, 18, 5, 5, 3, 13, 15, 3, 10, 
10, 7, 2, 5, 6, 16, 18, 5, 4, 5, 1, 5, 8, 1, 24, 11, 4, 1, 6, 
14, 5, 10, 6, 15, 6, 5, 9, 8, 2, 8, 7, 10, 1, 11, 5, 9, 2, 12, 
8, 11, 18, 7, 3, 14, 19, 2, 2, 2, 1, 5, 7, 13, 8, 9, 12, 13, 
2, 9, 3, 5, 2, 13, 4, 4, 10, 3, 6, 9, 10, 7, 1, 8, 28, 14, 5, 
13, 4, 11, 2, 1, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5, 1, 6, 4, 3, 10, 6, 5, 6, 24, 
5, 4, 8, 14, 2, 2, 11, 20, 3, 23, 18, 8, 5, 4, 10, 3, 4, 2, 11, 
15, 4, 4, 13, 7, 4, 9, 8, 3, 15, 1, 8, 3, 16, 5, 1, 11, 2, 6, 
2, 5, 4, 5, 4, 16, 3, 12, 5, 2, 4, 1, 5, 6, 3, 11, 4, 2, 3, 3, 
7, 1, 1, 18, 2, 21, 1, 3, 1, 2, 6, 3, 2, 2, 4, 13, 1, 2, 11, 
1, 15, 7, 5, 5, 2, 3, 4, 10, 6, 3, 5, 1, 6, 4, 6, 18, 4, 3, 5, 
4, 12, 3, 4, 19, 13, 11, 2, 6, 10, 7, 18, 1, 8, 28, 1, 22, 4, 
9, 8, 1, 6, 5, 14, 9, 1, 1, 10, 4, 16, 18, 1, 1, 6, 9, 7, 3, 
5, 18, 1, 5, 6, 8, 5, 39, 4, 6, 17, 11, 4, 2, 6, 1, 1, 9, 7, 
2, 7, 1, 7, 9, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 7), P.A = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), L.PA = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1)), .Names = c("Date", "Plant_ID", "Leaf", "P.A", "L.PA"), row.names = c(NA, 
-800L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: Could you provide the data using `dput(your data)` instead of an image?

Comment: The data you provide has only one date. Could you do as I've suggested in my previous comment?

Comment: Yes sorry, i’m On the train home but once i get somewhere with WiFi i’ll Log onto my laptop and do so!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to copy the data into the question, i've copied the output from dput(head(DF)) I hope that is okay? I couldn't paste the whole dput(DF) as i ran out of characters :)

Comment: Your `dput` cannot be read. There might be missing parenetheses. Please check what you posted as we would run on our ends: `DFP <- structure(....)`

Comment: Okay cheers i'll have another go!

Comment: Okay i've had to try and take a subset named: DFY as I cannot include the full dataframe as it is too large and it reaches my character limit. And a head of my normal data only has one date! It probably also converts P.A and U.PA to numeric but they should be factors? sorry hopefully this is useful

Comment: try `par(mfrow=c(1,2))` to put the two side by side?

Comment: Yes, I did consider that but I want to group these two graphs and quite a few more to save space and make it look nicer, grouped bar charts seem a nicer option for that! Thanks for the idea though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for the help I eventually worked it out, this problem may be applicable only to myself but just incase someone else has the same problem here is how I did it:

The data frame needed to be reorganised to allow for easier plotting

```
     DFP.A <- table(DF3$Date,DF3$P.A)
    DFLP.A <- table(DF3$Date,DF3$L.PA)
    dfa<-as.data.frame(DFP.A)
    dfb<-as.data.frame(DFLP.A)

#This gives the frequencies of upper and lower infected leaves on each date in two different data frames
# i then rename the columns mostly to make it easier for myself
    DFP.A
    DFLP.A
    colnames(dfa)[which(names(dfa) == "Var1")] <- "Date"
    colnames(dfa)[which(names(dfa) == "Var2")] <- "infected"
    colnames(dfa)[which(names(dfa) == "Freq")] <- "Upper_infected"

# i remove the Unifected ones from the data frames (those that have a 0)
  dfa<-dfa[dfa$infected!="0",]
    dfa <- subset(dfa, select = - infected)

    colnames(dfb)[which(names(dfb) == "Var1")] <- "Date"
    colnames(dfb)[which(names(dfb) == "Var2")] <- "infected"
    colnames(dfb)[which(names(dfb) == "Freq")] <- "Lower_infected"
    dfb<-dfb[dfb$infected!="0",]
    dfb <- subset(dfb, select = - infected)

    dfc<- merge(dfa,dfb, by = "Date")


    # melt the dataframe to make it more easily graphed

    library(reshape)
    dfd <- melt(dfc, id=c("Date"))

    # now attempt the graphs finally 

    ggplot(dfd, aes(factor(Date), value, fill = variable )) + 
      geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
      scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[The final grouped bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrxEe.png)